# Telegram api: send text and photos in one message

Tags: python-2.7, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to write a telegram bot, which send wall posts from VK group to the telegram channel.
I use pyTelegramBotAPI.

```
        post = u'{!s}'.format(item['text'])
        bot.send_message(CHANNEL_NAME, post)

        PHOTO_URL = str(item['attachments']['photo']['photo_604'])
        img_file = urllib2.urlopen(PHOTO_URL)
        im = StringIO(img_file.read())
        bot.send_photo(CHANNEL_NAME, im)
```

Is it possible to send text and photo in one message? Maybe you can advise me another library for telegram bot or some another magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sendPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) method has a parameter `caption`. It will appear below the picture.

When using pyTelegramBotAPI simply adding a third parameter as caption should work.

`bot.send_photo(CHANNEL_NAME, im,"Caption goes here")`